# Evaluation of $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(ax) \sin^n(bx) dx$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, parametric

As it is a kinda famous integral I thought I would find something on MSE but I didn't so here I am. If there is, link it in the comments and I will delete the question.

How do I evaluate $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(ax) \sin^n(bx) dx$$
$$a,b,n \in \mathbb{Z}, b\neq0, n\geq 0$$

The answer is $$\begin{cases}
(-1)^{n/2} (-1)^m \frac{2 \pi}{2^n} \binom{n}{m} & n \text{ even},\ |a| = |b (2m-n)| \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$$m \geq 0$$

Comment: I just gave a plain explanation for getting all the pieces of your formula.

Comment: I upvoted you. I'm waiting to see if there are more approaches.

Comment: What amounts to the same as Jack's answer but may be a bit more straightforward is to use the fact that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{kix}\,dx$ equals $2\pi$, if $k=0$ and vanishes otherwise. Also use the formulas $\cos t=(e^{it}+e^{-it})/2$, $\sin t=(e^{it}-e^{-it})/2i$. Apply binomial theorem to the sine (that explains where the binomial coefficient comes from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, you are integrating an odd function over an interval that is symmetric with respect to the origin, hence the answer is $0$. If $n$ is even, compute the Fourier cosine series of $\sin^n(bx)$ by exploiting the De Moivre identity and the binomial theorem. Since: 
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(ax)\cos(mx)\,dx = \pi\cdot \delta_{a,m},$$
the integral will be $\pm\pi$ times a binomial coefficient times a power of two iff $b\mid a$, zero otherwise.